# Dashboard in GWT

Tags: gwt, dashboard

I'm making an application to manage temporary worker for differents departments. So each day supervisors create 2 "shifts" one for  the day and one for the night. A shift permit to save  workers and can have three states:

1. There is no shift
2. A shift can be planned and not confirm
3. A shift is confirmed

So I want to make a kind of dashboard where supervisor can see for example for a period all the shifts which are not created, shifts which are confirmed or not with visual effect. 
I want to do something like that: https://mon-partage.fr/f/FAd6HXXS/

200,511,512... are the departments, J/N represents shift day and shift night and red color is for shift which are not created, orange is for shift which are not confirmed and green is for the confirmed shift...
I looked for a library to do that such as gxt,smartgwt but I didn't see a component which could help me.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid or FlexTable with css that sets background colors of cells